# Typewriter Effect UILabel width issue

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

I want to have a UILabel in the middle of the screen that starts from the left of the screen. The UILabel will get updated every second from a Timer to simulate a typewriter effect. So to display "Album releases", the UILabel will show this series of text:

A
Al
Alb
Albu
Album
Album
Album r
Album re
Album rel
Album rele
Album relea
Album releas
Album release
Album releases

The label has a black background. So I want to make sure the width fits the text. But if the text is too long then the width should go up to the screen width and then breaks into a second line. I tried using numberOfLines = 0 and sizeToFit to achieve that. But the issue is that for some reason, one letter is being written on a line. I cannot manage to fix that. Here's some code:

```
    private let taglinesLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        ...
        taglinesLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 0, height: 0)
        ...
    }

   public func showText() {
       ...
       startTimer()
       ...
   }

  func startTimer () {
      guard timer == nil else { return }

      timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.1),
          target      : self,
          selector    : #selector(onTimer),
          userInfo    : nil,
          repeats     : true)
    }

   @objc private func onTimer() {
            let tagline = taglines[taglineIndex]
            if(taglineCharacterIndex < tagline.count) {
                let substring = tagline.prefix(taglineCharacterIndex)
                print(substring)
                taglinesLabel.text = String(substring)
                taglinesLabel.sizeToFit()
                taglineCharacterIndex += 1
            } 
    }
```

[image]

How to constraint the UILabel to expand its width and not go to the next line like shown in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...

First, use auto-layout and constraints instead of `.sizeToFit()`.

Second, let's replace the `UILabel` with a non-editable, non-scrolling `UITextView` because:

- It gives us a visually nice "padding" around the text
- It keeps the text at the top (if we have set a height for the view)
- It avoids a weird "line jumping" when the text wraps

So, start with an example controller that puts an instance of our custom `TypingView` 40-points from the Top and from each side. We'll also give it four sample "taglines" and we'll start the timer in `viewDidAppear`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = TypingView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            // no bottom or height constraint
            //  we let the TypingView set its own height
        ])
        
        testView.taglines = [
            "First sample string.",
            "This is the Second sample tagline.",
            "This tagline will be long enough that it will wrap onto at least two lines.",
            "Here is the final tagline.",
        ]
        
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        testView.startTimer()
    }
    
}
```

Now, our custom `UIView` subclass:

```
class TypingView: UIView {

    public var taglines: [String] = []

    private var taglineIndex: Int = 0
    private var timer: Timer!
    private var taglineCharacterIndex: Int = 0
    
    private let taglinesLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .regular)
        v.textColor = .white
        v.backgroundColor = .black
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.isEditable = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .black
        taglinesLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(taglinesLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            taglinesLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            taglinesLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            taglinesLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            taglinesLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
    }

    func startTimer () {
        guard timer == nil else { return }
        
        timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.1),
            target      : self,
            selector    : #selector(onTimer),
            userInfo    : nil,
            repeats     : true)
    }
    
    @objc private func onTimer() {
        guard taglineIndex < taglines.count else {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            return
        }
        let tagline = taglines[taglineIndex]
        if taglineCharacterIndex < tagline.count + 1 {
            let substring = tagline.prefix(taglineCharacterIndex)
            taglinesLabel.text = String(substring)
            taglineCharacterIndex += 1
        } else if taglineCharacterIndex < tagline.count + 6 {
            // this will provide a half-second "pause" before going to the next tagline
            taglineCharacterIndex += 1
        } else {
            taglineIndex += 1
            taglineCharacterIndex = 0
        }
    }
    
}
```

It will look like this (adding 1 character every 1/10th second):

[image]

and with enough text to wrap:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *in response to comment...*

To get the view to expand horizontally as the text gets longer, change the `trailing` constraint (in `ViewController`) from:

```
testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
```

to:

```
testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
```

Now it will grow wider with each character, but only until it reaches 40-points from the right side.

You could also replace the `trailing` constraint with a `width` constraint if that would better suit your needs.

For example:

```
testView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 240.0),
```

would limit its width to 240-points.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DonMag for putting the effort into this. This is almost perfect solution. There is one requirement that is not met. The width should not be fixed. So for example in your first screenshot "First sample string.", I expect the black background to be wrapping the text and be smaller. What adjustment is needed for that?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi - see the **Edit** to my answer.